# Using bootstrap datepicker methods with AngularJS ui-date

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, bootstrap-datepicker

I would like to use the setDateDisabled method in bootstrap-datepicker, but unsure on how to use it in angular.

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html#setdatesdisabled

I managed to initialize the datepicker nicely with

```
<input ui-date="datepickerOptions"  ng-model="rigDate.date" />
```

and this on the javascript side

```
   $scope.datepickerOptions = {
            orientation: 'top',
            startDate: PayPeriodService.getStartDate(),
            endDate: PayPeriodService.getEndDate(),
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        };
```

using angular-ui

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use bootstrap datepicker by using directives and have the link object within directive to manipulate the datepicker using jquery code.